# How to push values in a list of lists in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qlist

In header file, I have this:

```
private:  
    Q_PROPERTY(QList <QList <QString> > dummy READ dummy WRITE setDummy NOTIFY dummyChanged)

    QList <QList <QString> > m_dummy;

public:  
    QList <QList <QString> > dummy() const
        {
            return m_dummy;
        }

public slots:
    void setDummy(QList <QList <QString> > arg)
        {
            if (m_dummy == arg)
                return;

            m_dummy = arg;
            emit dummyChanged(arg);
        }

signals:      
    void dummyChanged(QList <QList <QString> > arg);
```

In CPP file, in a function I have written:

```
QList <QString> p;
p.push_back("abc");
p.push_back("def");

QList <QString> q;
q.push_back("ghi");
q.push_back("jkl");

dummy.push_back (p);
dummy.push_back (q);
```

Compilation error I get is:

error: '((TablesAndChartsDatabaseQueries*)this)->TablesAndChartsDatabaseQueries::dummy' does not have class type
     dummy.push_back (p);

What point am I missing?

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code. Could you provide the code of your header file with the Q_PROPERTY declaration?

Comment: Btw. you could use `QStringList` instead of `QList<QString>`, but that shouldn't be an issue in your case.

Comment: @thomas_b I cannot add more code. The SO system is saying you have too much code so add some details.

Comment: @thomas_b Ah, fooled the system, finally.

Comment: I guess you should call `m_dummy.push_back(p)` and not `dummy.push_back(p)` because dummy is the method to get the "dummy".

Comment: @thomas_b thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[thomas_b pointed out the error correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891354/how-to-push-values-in-a-list-of-lists-in-qt#comment55548049_33891354) as follows:

> I guess you should call m_dummy.push_back(p) and not dummy.push_back(p) because dummy is the method to get the "dummy".

I think, a better way to set the desired value would have been to call the `setDummy` function and let it do the job it is created for.

```
QList <QList <QString> > localDummy;
QList <QString> p;
p.push_back("abc");
p.push_back("def");

QList <QString> q;
q.push_back("ghi");
q.push_back("jkl");

localDummy.push_back (p);
localDummy.push_back (q);

setDummy (localDummy);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to call the function dummy() instead of accessing dummy directly. So try `dummy().push_back()` or `dummy().append()`.

Accessing a function using .bla() gives the compile error you get:

`memberFunction.bla() -> does not have class type`, just tested it.

So your "dummy.push_back()" tries to use the function in a wrong way and not the property.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. As a side note, `dummy().push_back()` won't work, if he wants to change the `m_dummy` member.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `dummy.append(q)` or `dummy.insert(q.size(), q)`

I wonder what "READ dummy WRITE setDummy NOTIFY dummyChanged" means.